# How to remove setting applying local memory_limit for php on an nginx server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, memory, settings

Upon checking the php memory_limit set on the laravel project hosted by the nginx server, it has a differing value for the local memory_limit and master memory_limit

[image]

I want the project's php memory_limit to follow the master setting (php.ini) rather than the local setting.

However I am unable to find where the memory limit of 1536M is being set on, ***can someone please point me in the right direction***

I have checked the following files

1. nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (No lines with memory_limit
   found)
2. nano /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf (;php_admin_value 128M)
3. nano /etc/php.ini (memory_limit = 128M)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce your issue.

Master value will be always from php.ini file only. When you update you need to restart nginx and php-fpm to get Updated value

But Local value will be from your laravel code. You might have set it in laravel files as below
`ini_set('memory_limit', '1536M');`

Search for 1536 or ini_set or memory_limit in your source code.

Hope this resolves your issue

Comment: I have searched through the entire project but dont have this line 'ini_set('memory_limit', '1536M');' anywhere.

Any other possibillities?

Comment: Can you check your .htaccess file, if there is any value configured.

Also Just search for value "1536" in whole project there might be some custom implementation

Comment: unfortunately i control F throughout my project already cannot find any 1536 value.

where can I find this .htaccess file?